# How can I list most recently viewed products by ALL users

Tags: magento-1.9

As the title suggests, I am after a function that can display 30 recently viewed products by all users - possibly other than the active user.

---

The code below does it. I now just need to exclude the active user from the list - who might be a guest.

```
$attributes = Mage::getSingleton('catalog/config')->getProductAttributes();

$this->_collection = Mage::getModel("reports/product_index_viewed")
                ->getCollection()
                ->addAttributeToSelect($attributes);


$this->_collection->excludeProductIds(Mage::getModel("reports/product_index_viewed")->getExcludeProductIds())
                    ->addUrlRewrite()
                    ->setPageSize(5)
                    ->setCurPage(1);

/* Price data is added to consider item stock status using price index */
$this->_collection->addPriceData();

$ids = $this->getProductIds();
if (empty($ids)) {
                $this->_collection->addIndexFilter();
} else {
                $this->_collection->addFilterByIds($ids);
}
$this->_collection->setAddedAtOrder();
if ($this-> _useProductIdsOrder && is_array($ids)) {
                $this->_collection->setSortIds($ids);
}

Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_visibility')
                ->addVisibleInSiteFilterToCollection($this->_collection);
$_products = $this->_collection;
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using DB query to perform this job.

```
$connection = Mage::getModel('core/resource')->getConnection('core_read');

$sql = 'SELECT * 
        FROM `report_viewed_product_index` 
        WHERE `store_id` = "' . Mage::app()->getStore()->getStoreId() . '"
        ' . (Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomerId() !== null ? 'AND `customer_id` <> ' . Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomerId() : '') . '
        ' . (Mage::getSingleton('log/visitor')->getId() !== null ? 'AND `visitor_id` <> ' . Mage::getSingleton('log/visitor')->getId() : '') . '
        ORDER BY `added_at` DESC 
        LIMIT 12';

$products = $connection->fetchAll($sql);
```

Why I did this? This is because when `getModel("reports/product_index_viewed")` Magento kept using products table; so getCollection() will provide you with a list of products. The ORM & luck of documentation wasn't an option - waste of time. Hence why the best solution was to utilise raw sql.